# Unable to understand "something out of something"

Tags: probability

I'm having a serious problem understanding a very very basic concept. I tried many times to reason it but I failed so here I'm bravely going to ask about it. When someone says "2 out of 3 people" have an issue $X$, that phrase is usually translated into $2/3$. But why? Why division? What does it mean? I'm not sure how to explain it to you.

But the only way now I can think of it is that we want to represent something with a percentage and that's why we are using division, because $x/y$ would be something always between zero and one, which can directly be translated into a percentage between 0%-100%.

But still it's so ambiguous to me "two out of three" ... this is somehow blurry ... $2+3$ is a very clear thing. I mean I'm just thinking about it right now. When someone usually says that phrase all I can think of is subtracting 2 from 3 and seeing 1.

Edit: "three people out of a hundred" 3/100, that would make it 3%. When I read such a phrase my mind thinks about it like this: if we have a 100 men, then 3 of them will be $X$ or will have $X$. But now "three out of five", that means if we have five people, then three of them will have $X$.

Comment: Is your problem with understanding the concept of ratio of number-of-people-with-the-problem to number-of-people-total, or is it with understanding why the words "out of" are used to express that concept? If it's the words, then it may be a better question for english.SE.

Comment: @HenningMakholm no not English problem. Somehow my brain is not able to *accept* the idea of that ratio, nor the way probability is discussed in textbooks. I understand what they mean and I can solve problems, but my brain is not able to *accept* the intuitions or the ideas. They are somehow obscure or not *clean*.

Answer (score 1):

If $2$ out of $3$ people have an issue $X$, then the number of people who have that issue is $\frac{2}{3}$ times the number of people.

Percentage is a pretty artificial concept; we only use it because it's a bit easier for people to understand numbers on a scale from $0$ to $100$ than from $0$ to $1$. But there's nothing at all special about the number $100$.

Comment: Your answer somehow touches on my issue but it couldn't fully solve it. The problem is that I'm unable to explain it. And I understand that my question doesn't have a concrete or clear question. I was just hoping if someone could figure out my problem by understanding the context.

Comment: My mind is somehow unwilling to accept the ideas ... they are somehow not *clean*